# Date in variable reading as "Invalid Date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, date

Using the following:

```
var timestart = $('.thisDiv').data("timestart");
var startDateTime = new Date(timestart);
```

to collect a date from a php file that is updating by ajax from this:

```
$TimeStart = date( 'Y,m,d,g,i', $TimeStart );

<div class="thisDiv" data-timestart="<?= $TimeStart ?>"></div>

var timestart = $('.thisDiv').data("timestart");
```

In console I'm getting the following when logging `timestart` and `startDateTime`:

```
2017,07,24,7,50
Invalid Date
```

If I paste the date that is output as follows

```
var startDateTime = new Date(2017,07,24,7,50);
```

Then it works fine. Any ideas why I'm getting Invalid Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timestart` variable (JavaScript) is just a string. So it's a string `2017,07,24,7,50`, and not those elements in order - which can't be used as separate parameters like `new Date()` expects.

Let's take a look at it!

```
var startDateTime = new Date(2017,07,24,7,50);   // Parameters in order - all OK!
var startDateTime = new Date("2017,07,24,7,50"); // A single string - single parameter, not OK!
```

You need to return a proper format of dates from PHP with a format that's valid in JavaScript. Per the ECMAScript standard, the valid format that should work across all browsers is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` (see the reference at the bottom). To define that from PHP, you would need to format it as such

```
$TimeStart = date('c', $TimeStart);
```

This would return a format such as `2017-07-24T21:08:32+02:00`.

**Alternatively**, you can use a splat/spread-operator `...` and split the string it into elements, which I find as the better approach than above.

```
var timestart = $('.thisDiv').data("timestart");  // Get the string: "2017,07,24,7,50"
timestart = timestart.split(",");                 // Split into array
var startDateTime = new Date(...timestart);       // Pass as arguments with splat-operator
```

- [Spread/splat operator in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [PHP `date()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [ECMAScript date string (JavaScript)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format)

Comment: I'm removing my answer in favor of this one, your explanation is mostly identical to mine and you get bonus points for mentioning the splat operator

Comment: You didn't have to remove your answer though, it was valid (and you were quicker than me with an answer, too!). ;-)

Comment: "2017-07-24 21:08:32" is not a "valid" [*ECMASript date string*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date-time-string-format). Parsing is implementation dependent and  returns an invalid Date in Safari at least. Instead of generating a string to parse, far better to pass appropriate values directly to the Date constructor.

Comment: @RobG Honestly, I wasn't aware. I've tested in other browsers, but seems like I've just had luck with the format working. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date from string format to numbers.

```js
var timestart = $('.thisDiv').data("timestart").split(",").map(Number);
var startDateTime = new Date(...timestart);
console.log(startDateTime)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thisDiv" data-timestart="2017,07,24,7,50"></div>
```